# (Branch.io) Referral integration in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, branch.io

I need assistance with if-

**1-** If I refer someone than he will get 10 coins and I will get 5 coins.

**2-** After 5 successful referral I want activate some feature for user.

> So my problem is how can I know that user has successfully achieved 5
>   referral?

I have integrated how to get credits and redeem credits but I have stuck how to know that i successfully referred five person.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Branch Referral History API](https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/api/#referral-history) to check if the referred user got credited the reward

> curl -XGET
>   'https://api.branch.io/v1/credithistory?branch_key=key_live_kaFuWw8WvY7yn1d9yYiP8gokwqjV0Swt&identity=steve'

For any further questions, reach out to integrations@branch.io and we would be happy to help you out.